# Excluding specific routes from VPN when connecting via NetworkManager

Tags: opensuse, networkmanager, openconnect

I am using NetworkManager's openconnect plugin to connect to a VPN server. I would like to exclude specific routes from VPN so that they go outside the VPN.

How can I do that with NetworkManager/openconnect?